# LinqToXML: accessing child elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I trying to figure out a solution for a tiny problem I have, but I didn't have much success in last two days. I've went through many posts here but I failed to find an adequate solution for myself. I know it's probably basic question for you guys, but it seems like I've lost focus and can think clearly about this issue.

So, this is the issue. I have a sample XML below, with the structure I need. What I want is to read this XML, go to the event I want and than read/ store  all test elements.

```
<Config>
<Events>
<Event_1>
        <NameOfEvent>SomeName:</NameOfEvent>
        <test id="test001">
                <xpath>"some xpath"</xpath>
                <value>someValue1</value>
                <tagName>none</tagName>
            </test>
            <test id="test002">
                <xpath>"some xpath"</xpath>
                <value>someValue2</value>
                <tagName>none1</tagName>
            </test>
            <test id="test003">
                <xpath>"some xpath"</xpath>
                <value>someValue3</value>
                <tagName>none2</tagName>
            </test>
        </Event_1>
        </Events>
        </Config>
```

What I`ve done so far is this:

```
 string EventCode="Event_1";
var doc= XDocument.Load(@"C:\new\test\testConfig.xml");
var result = from y in doc.Descendants(EventCode).
 Where(y =>(string)y.Element("path").Attribute("id")=="test001"
                     {
                         NameOfEvent = y.Element("NameOfEvent").Value,
                         xpath= y.Element("test").Element("xpath").Value
                         value =y.Element("test").Element("value").Value,
                         tag =y.Element("test").Element("tagName").Value
                     };
```

Than, I want to use foreach loop, to access all test elements. But, I`m only able to access chiled nodes of first element test.
Can you help with this? Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your XML has no specific namespaces

```
var evt = (from el in doc.Descendants("test")
           where el.Parent.Name == "Event_1"
           group el by el.Parent.Element("NameOfEvent").Value into g
           select new {
               Name = g.Key,
               Tests = g.Select(x => new {
                   XPath = x.Element("xpath").Value,
                   Value = x.Element("value").Value,
                   TagName = x.Element("tagName").Value
               })
           }).FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine("Event name: " + evt.Name);
foreach (var test in evt.Tests)
{
    Console.WriteLine(test.XPath);
    Console.WriteLine(test.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(test.TagName);
}
```

[Live demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QMllTa)

Comment: Thank You a lot! It works great. So I had completely wrong approach.